# Referência em Latex, modelo IEEE

Tags: latex

Olá estou redigindo textos em latex pelo editor online Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/) que acho ser muito bom. Este possui diversos modelos de diversos artigos, inclusive em IEEE, que estou usando (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/preparation-of-papers-for-ieee-sponsored-conferences-and-symposia/zfnqfzzzxghk#.VrC1xrIrLIU). O problema é que nesse modelo a referencia é direta, vc tem uma secção References.

Eu gostaria de fazer a referência indireta, com o uso do `\cite{reference}` sendo que esta referência estaria num arquivo ref.bib

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, dá. É só você abrir a aba "Project" (clique no botão de respective nome, na barra de ferramentas superior), e adicionar o seu arquivo `ref.bib` como um recurso do projeto. Use o botão "Add files..." para isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ah, no seu arquivo principal (`main.tex`) não esqueça de "apontar" para o arquivo de referências, substituindo as referências manualmente feitas por algo do tipo:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEconf}
\bibliography{ref}
```

(onde `ref` é o nome do arquivo de bibliografia, sem a extensão).

Comment: Gosto de ver perguntas e resposta sobre LaTeX aqui no SOpt. :-)

Comment: Obrigado seguindo esses passos consegui, porém a referência com o \cite{aj-js} não funcionou, ele deu o erro "LaTeX Warning: Citation `aj-jc' on page 1 undefined on input line 52." no .bib eu tenho                                       
@ARTICLE{aj-jc,
   author = {Andreas Junghanns and Jonathan Schaeffer},
   title = {Sokoban: Enhancing general single-agent search methods using domain knowledge},
   journal = {Artificial Intelligence},
   year = {2001},
   volume = {129},
   pages = {219-251}
}   alguma ideia?

Comment: Não dá pra saber sem detalhes. A referência está correta mesmo? (você menciona que usa `\cite{aj-js}`, só que no bib você tem a chave como `aj-jc` - **que não é a mesma**!). Além disso, funciona no LaTeX local, ou só da erro no Overleaf? De todas as formas, se o problema é outro, você deve abrir uma nova pergunta (e não se esqueça de preparar um exemplo mínimo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel).